# Recursion gives correct answer for minimum Coin Change but dynamic programming gives wrong answer

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am trying to do this problem for quite a few hours but I can't think intuitively about it. Having sort of a mental block regarding it. After many tries I was able to get recursion solution correct for cases where solution exist. So I have following questions:

1. Recursion program is giving correct solution for input in which solution exist. How to return 'No solution exist' where solution doesn't exist. Ex for Coins [3,10], no solution exist for change 17.
2. What is the mistake in DP program? I tried using memoization technique where I created a dictionary and added values to it but the program is not working correctly.

```
import math
def findMinCoins(denomination, change):
    #recursive solution
    minCoins = change
    if(len(denomination )== 0 or change ==0): #when there are no coins or change is 0
        return 0
    elif(change in denomination):
        return 1
    elif(change < min(denomination)):
        return float("inf")
    else:
        for i in denomination:
            if(i<=change):
                numCoins = 1 + findMinCoins(denomination, change - i)
                if(numCoins < minCoins):
                    minCoins = numCoins
    return minCoins

c = [3,10]
d = 30

print findMinCoins(c,d)
```

Now here is DP solution.

```
import math
coinsDict = {}

def findMinCoins(denomination, change):
    minCoins = change
    if(len(denomination )== 0 or change ==0):
        return 0
    elif(change in denomination):
        return 1
    elif(change < min(denomination)):
        return float("inf")
    else:
        for i in denomination:
            if (coinsDict.get(change)):
                print 'dictionaty',change, coinsDict.get(change)
                return coinsDict[change]
            elif(i<=change):
                numCoins = 1 + findMinCoins(denomination, change - i)
                if(numCoins < minCoins):
                    minCoins = numCoins
                    print change, numCoins
                    coinsDict[change] = numCoins

    return minCoins

c = [3,10]
d = 30

print findMinCoins(c,d)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  "not working correctly" is not a problem description.  Show your output and the logic trace you've run.

Comment: @Prune In DP program for input coins=[3,10] and change = 30. The output is 10 coins but it should be 3 coins as [10,10,10] is the minumum number of coins required. I think the problem exist because I've added to dictionary first wrt coin 3 first. Now when program calls itself recursively for coin 10, it checks if value exist for a particular change. So it uses 3's value for 10 also.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way you use the memos.  If you've found a solution for a particular amount of change, you never consider that there might be a better solution.  Look at the logic

```
    if (coinsDict.get(change)):
        print 'dictionaty',change, coinsDict.get(change)
        return coinsDict[change]
    elif(i<=change):
        numCoins = 1 + findMinCoins(denomination, change - i)
```

On your first pass through the recursion, you walk all the way down and find that you can handle 30 cents with 10 coins of 3.  Then you unwind back to the top of the stack and try again with a 10-cent piece ... but before you bother to look for a solution the above logic says, "I already know how to handle 30 cents: return 10 coins."  It never gets to explore solutions involving other amounts.

If you reverse the order of checking your denominations, you'll get the desired solution.  Make sure you try other test cases: you should find that this simple repair isn't enough to fix your logic.  For instance, try

c = [3, 11, 13]
d = 22

If you fail to look for better solutions, you'll find the 4-coin solution of 13, 3, 3, 3 and miss the 11, 11 answer.

Comment: Thanks Prune. I mistakenly was adding element in dictionary in the For  loop. The programs shows correct output 3 for input coins[3,10] change =30 when I write "coinsDict[change] = numCoins" outside for loop just above return minCoins.

Comment: Excellent!  Does it also handle the case of ([3, 11, 13], 22) ?

Comment: Yes prints 2 in a blink. Can you suggest how do I edit the code so  when I have some case like ([3, 11, 13], 23) where no solution exists it returns 0. Mistakenly wrote "coinsDict[change] = numCoins" above instead of "coinsDict[change] = minCoins"

Comment: One of two possibilities: (1) Write a wrapper function that calls findMinCoins.  Its only purpose is to check the return value: if it includes "inf", return 0 instead to the main program; (2) rework your logic for returning failure.  First, return a signal value instead of "inf" (returning a string when the rest of your logic expects an integer is not cool).  Second, where you have **numCoins = 1 + findMinCoins...**, split this up to check the return value and propagate failure back to the top level.  Is that clear enough?